# Performance monitor logs are not getting generated on windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, perfmon

On Windows Server 2008 R2 and windows Server 2012 Standard machines:

- I have added the Data Collector set in Performance monitor.
- I scheduled it for 4 hours

Seems that the task is being started as the folder is getting created but the log reports are not generating.

Comment: what happens when you manually run the task

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the [generation of reports does not work](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/971714/the-report-generation-process-may-stop-responding-when-you-run-perfmon.exe-with-the-active-directory-diagnostics-template-to-generate-a-report-on-a-windows-server-2008-based-domain-controller). In this situation, you can generate a report manually (by the way it works much faster than Perfmon):

1. After data collector finished run `cmd.exe` and go to folder with collected data (location depends on your settings)
2. Run `tracerpt *.blg *.etl -report report.html -f html`

Your report will be in `report.html`